# image cropping c#

Tags: c#, .net, image

I want to do image cropping.
I saw following link.

[Image cropping](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

But what i want to do is as follows.
I want to crop the image calculating dimension from its centre.
So for example if my image is 100 px and cropping i want result to be 50 px.
i want to leave 25 px each on left and right hand side and make the width 50 px.

Has anyone done it before?

Comment: WPF, WinForms etc.??? + What have you tried???

Comment: -1 I just checked out the blog post you linked to and your work is already done for you there. On top of what is written there I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, certainly people have done that before. Now, how about you show us [what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), explain where you are stuck and post the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple.

Say you have `width` and `height` (of your source image), and you need your output to be in `cropped_width` and `cropped_height`.

For start, we need to calculate center of the source image:

```
int x_center=width/2;
int y_center=height/2;
```

Then, we know that we need output picture to be of defined size, so we take HALF of the size to the left-right:

```
int x_source=x_center-cropped_width/2;
int y_source=y_center-cropped_height/2;
```

and finally, you have your rectangle for cropping:

```
Rect r = new Rect(x_source, y_source, cropped_width, cropped_height);
```

use some form of `DrawImage()` to copy that rectangle to the place you need.